# Detecting server side issues from within an ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

That is my jquery code:

```
$(function() {  
$("#edit_union").click(function() {
    var tuzove = $("#tuzove").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();
    var union_owner = $("#union_owner").val();
    var union_name = $("#union_name").val();
    var uid = $("#uid").val();
    var dataString = 'tuzove='+ tuzove + '&description=' + description + '&union_owner=' + union_owner + '&union_name=' + union_name + '&uid=' + uid;  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajax/admp_ajax.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {
            $(".adm_panel_serach_user").append("<br/><span style=' color: #0099ff; font-weight: bold;'>Success.</span>");
        }  
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

That is ajax/admp_ajax.php page:

```
include_once 'classes/admin_panel.php';
$admpanel = new adminPanal();

if ($_POST['tuzove'] && $_POST['description'] && $_POST['union_owner'] && $_POST['union_owner'] && $_POST['uid'])
$admpanel->editUnion($_POST['tuzove'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['union_owner'], $_POST['union_name'], $_POST['uid']);
```

That is editUnion function:

```
public function editUnion($tyzove, $description, $ownerName, $unionName, $unionId) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `union` SET tuzove = '" . $tyzove . "', description = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($description) . "', owner_id = '" . $this->getUserId($ownerName) . "' WHERE name = '" . $unionName . "'");

    if ($ownerName == $ownerName)
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET union_rank = '0', union_id = '0' WHERE username = '" . $ownerName . "'");

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET union_rank = '1', union_id = '" . $unionId . "' WHERE username = '" . $ownerName . "'");
}
```

Problem is that, when I click edit_union button write Success, but don't update union :(.

Comment: This is an interesting comparison: `if ($ownerName == $ownerName)`

Comment: May be it needs to be `if ($ownerName == $unionName)`

Comment: can you add or die() to you mysql_query()-function? Eg. $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE ...") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: Does the execution reach the code in question?  Do a little debugging, please.  If a MySQL query is sent to the database, what is the actual query?  What, if any, errors are encountered on the server-side code?  (You don't report them to the client-side code, so using your client-side code exclusively as a measure of success seems... unwise.)

Comment: This is not a problem, first mysql_query must be fulfilled next others

Comment: Nohting wrong with the AJAX request, therefore there is no error. You could have a htmlentities problem if you try to send char like "+" in your description : use a JSON map to send your data {tuzove :tuzove, description : description, ...)

Comment: The title of this post is pretty misleading also. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your php page will return some content whether the sql query fails or not.  This means that success will always be fired unless the page cannot be loaded for some reason.  SQL failures will not cause it to fail.

Therefore you will always get your success printed but the update itself may fail.  Try running the php page by itself in the browser and see any errors sql kicks up.  You can also try printing the sql queries to the screen using echo statements in php and then copy these onto the sql commandline or into phpmyadmin etc.

Also a side note, since your query info is coming from a form / input fields you need to be very careful to prevent sql injection and the like.  Look into using mysqli and prepared statements instead.

Comment: ok and have you tried checking the sql query executed by php when its called from your ajax request?  It may be as someone said earlier that post variables are not being sent correctly.  Try echoing out in the php and just alert out the response to see what the query actually is.

Comment: I add echo $_POST['union_name'] and echo 'test'; in ajax/admp_ajax.php but I don't see nothing when click button.

Comment: well you will need to add an alert to the success function.
    `success: function(data) { alert(data); }`
I think this should work, although I'm just going off the top of my head at the moment.  This should at aleast alert anything that the php code is returning, you will probably see some sort of error relating to your mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

You ajax success function is not doing anything..it is just updating success...which is fine as per JS side..check the data which is getting sent,..dont use dataString ..infact create dataobject like

```
var dataObject=new Object();
dataObject.union_name=union_name;
```

debeug your server side code..I think data is not getting submitted successfully.